# PDF generation using empty images using FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I have a php  student application file displaying database details,and i am exporting this page to pdf using fpdf. but if a student as uploaded the photo, pdf is generating but if student is not uploaded the photo, pdf is not generating. how can i generate a pdf.

Comment: Check if image exists and do not put the image in the PDF when it does not. You will have to provide some code if you want our help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check file_exists from official php website:

http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-exists.php

conditionally print (if exists) or not (if not). If you try to print something that does not exists it will provoke errors.